# Retrieving public properties from an MSI file

Tags: windows, msi

Is there a tool or mechanism for retrieving the available public properties from a Windows MSI file?

Some vendors that supply MSI files don't document these themselves, so I'm curious to see if there is a way to expose these without the source code.

Comment: [Microsoft's ORCA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx), [Pantaray's SuperORCA](http://www.pantaray.com/msi_super_orca.html) and most every other MSI edit will allow you to browse/edit any table including the `Property` table.  Did you have a specific work-flow or use-case outside just poking-around in the MSI?

Comment: I wanted to understand the available public properties so they could be passed accurately during installation, without having to query the vendor or documentation (as this is not always possible). With Puppet we can pass in MSI properties during installation (we wrap misexec.exe), so its handy to have this ability.

Comment: There could be other public properties that you can pass to control the installation although they're not listed in the Properties table. Properties can be set dynamically depending on a condition, Registry search for example. So vendor documentation is the better source of information.

Comment: You can also run the installation with verbose logging to see how properties change their values.

Comment: Sorry about the delay - I've tried Orca and its fascinating, but I've confirmed the behaviour you describe @AlexeyIvanov - that is, some properties won't appear. I confirmed this with splunk.msi and its docs. I'm guessing the ones that appear in Orca have defaults, but this isn't a canonical list. Can you explain a bit more about the verbose logging methodology?

Answer (score 11):

[Lessmsi](http://lessmsi.activescott.com/) provides a command line as well as interactive application for retrieving any attribute from the .msi.

Interactively, open the .msi then go to *Table view* and select or type "Property". However while this gives the property names it doesn't give the valid values for said property.(Or I haven't discovered the right place to look.)

Command line to list Properties table to console (frustratingly, can't be captured with simple `> output.csv` redirect)

```
lessmsi l -t Property ...\path\to\setup.msi
```

Answer (score 4):

**lessmsi** is a great tool that certainly works here if you're willing to pop open its GUI and do some manual investigation. However, I will say, that the following command does not reliably present all properties:

```
lessmsi l -t Property <msi_name>
```

One way to (better) guarantee that you get all the possible properties is to actually perform either an installation, repair, or uninstall with the MSI file and log the process. The following command records only the properties and nothing else:

```
<msi_name> /lp! <msi_property_logfile>
```

The above command is equivalent to:

```
msiexec /lp! <msi_property_logfile> /i <msi_name>
```

My preferred method, however, is to *not* actually install/remove/repair (and to simply extract instead). The advantages this method has over **lessmsi** is that it doesn't require a 3rd-party utility (i.e. **lessmsi**), and it doesn't require you to mess with any installations. Given that you have enough disk space to actually install the program, you can do:

```
msiexec /a <msi_name> /lp! <msi_property_logfile> TARGETDIR=<absolute_path_to_extract_to>
```

Note that the `<absolute_path_to_extract_to>` can point to a nonexistent directory (the command will create the directories necessary or fail).

If you hate the installation UI for whatever reason you can append the `/qr` option, which will 'reduce' and possibly eliminate the UI without impairing the property logging process. Be warned however--if you go "lower" than the reduced UI (viz. `/qb`|`/passive` or `/qn`|`/quiet`), your `<msi_property_logfile>` may be missing some properties.

Comment: The problem of this method is: you have to actually run the installer. Even you install it to a nonstandard targetdir, you still messed up the registers.

Answer (score 1):

Given that MSI file store public properties in an internal database, you can actually just query them out using VBScript and SQL.

[Here's an example script](http://scriptbox.toll.at/index.php?showcontent=Get%20MSI-File%20properties.vbs&list=1) that will return all properties stored in the MSI file. It is convention to use capital letters to define public properties, so that is how they are usually identifiable.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm doing it now is by using the Carbon Powershell module.
To install the module type:

```
Install-Module -Name 'Carbon' -AllowClobber
```

Then simply

```
msi your_msi_path.msi
```

Example:

```
msi putty-64bit-0.70-installer.msi

ProductName                 ProductVersion Manufacturer ProductCode                         

-----------                 -------------- ------------ -----------                         

PuTTY release 0.70 (64-bit) 0.70.0.0       Simon Tatham 45b3032f-22cc-40cd-9e97-4da7095fa5a2
```

Comment: Your example does not show any properties!?

Answer (score -1):

I think that now probably the best way of doing it is using powershell.
Here is a script that does the job really well:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-MsiDatabaseProperties-09d9c87c

Comment: This answer is just a link, which can change/disappear.

Comment: There are other answers that are simply a link.
I don't feel comfortable copying and pasting other people code.I think my answer gives an alternative option and I really don't understand the down vote.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer specifically the section Provide context for links

Comment: Sure it's been a long time but the link is now down and I was looking for alternatives.

Comment: @DavidMakogon must be some type of clairvoyant!!!